# remove row in parent-child table in Entity framework

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a table (Code first, EF6, Sql Server):

```
public int Srl { get; set; }
public StringName{ get; set; }
public Nullable<int> Parent { get; set; }
```

I want to delete a row in table with special `Srl` and all of child of that. Note that the child of a row may be something like:

```
row->
    Child1->
            Child1-1
    Child2->
    Child3->
           Child3-1
           Child3-2->
                   Child3-2-1
    Child4
```

I write this method:

```
private void DeleteObjectAndChildren(int id)
        {
            var menu = db.Menus.Where(m => m.Parent == id).ToList();
            foreach (var item in menu)
            {
                var child = db.Menus.Where(m => m.Parent == item.Srl).ToList();

                if (child.Count != 0)
                {
                    DeleteObjectAndChildren(item.Srl);
                }
                else
                {
                    db.Menus.Remove(item);
                }
            }
            db.SaveChanges();
        }
```

The code running without error but nothing change in database. Any body know whats my wrong?

And could anyone suggest **better** way to delete a row and all of child of that?

Comment: Can you post the full entity model in question? The way it is now (w/o any navigation property), I don't see how you can define the relationship.

Answer (score 1):

One of the methods, you can delete it after you find the children.

```
MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();
public List<Menus> GetChildren(int id)
{
    return db.Menus.Where(i => i.Parent == id || i.Id == id).ToList().Union(db.Menus.Where(i => i.Parent == id).ToList().SelectMany(i => GetChildren(i.Id)).ToList()).ToList();            
}
public void DeleteMenus(int id)
{
    GetChildren(id).ForEach(i => db.Entry(i).State = System.Data.Entity.EntityState.Deleted);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```